# How to update a document based on two filter conditions?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, selector, querying

I have a document structure that looks like this:

```
type Document = {
  _id: string
  title: string
  variants: VariantType[]
}

type VariantType = {
  timestamp: Int
  active: Boolean
  content: any[]
}
```

I'm trying to filter a document based on two filter conditions in one query. First I want to match the _id and then find a specific variant based on a timestamp.

My previous version of the query was filtering based on the `active` key.

```
const updatedDocument = await allDocuments
        .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: mongoId, 'variants.active': false }, .... };
```

Changing it to

```
const updatedDocument = await allDocuments
        .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: mongoId, 'variants.timestamp': timestamp }, .... };
```

returns null.

Can mongo even match a document like this. I saw that there is an `$eq` query selector but I can't seem to get it working either.

Comment: Check if the value of variants.active is null in the db. Mongo doesn't default to false. It is stored as null.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I the problem was with the timestamp I was sending to the server. I was getting it from the wrong place and it wasn't matching any of the variants.